# I`m trying to Calculate Daily Returns for the S&P TSX 60 using basic python and it's libraries

Tags: python, pandas

I`m trying to Calculate Daily Returns for the S&P TSX 60

```
sp_tsx_daily_returns = sp_tsx_history_df.pct_change()
sp_tsx_daily_returns.head()
```

but I get the error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your data type for the column is string, it needs to be changed to float

Comment: I`m trying to change for int but I cant. Does it have to be a float type?
sp_tsx_history_df = sp_tsx_history_df['Close'].str.replace('$', '')
sp_tsx_history_df['Close'].astype(int)

Comment: best if you post a bit of your dataframe. it doesn't have to be float, but assuming your data isn't whole numbers